# Restringir regras do .htacess apenas para uma pasta

Tags: htaccess, cookies

Preciso otimizar uma página que está dentro de uma pasta **/site** e gostaria de ativar os cookies, porém eles não podem ser habilitados para as outras pastas.

Como posso fazer uma condição ou regra que limite apenas a essa pasta?

Código

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2592000 seconds"
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar a solução aqui, pois pode ser útil para outros usuários.

Após muitas pesquisas descobri que é necessário criar um arquivo httpd.conf com a tag **directory** para limitar as regras apenas para a pasta desejada...

**httpd.conf**

```
<Directory /site>
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Cookies
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

[Link Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)

Answer (score 0):

Se não tive permissão administrativa ao servidor, o que ocorre muito em servidores *shared* basta jogar o `.htaccess` na pasta desejada:

```
public_html
├───index.php
├───.htaccess
├───images
|   ├───.htaccess
|   └───1.jpg
├───css
|   ├───.htaccess
|   └───main.css
└───js
    ├───.htaccess
    └───main.js
```

Cada pasta com o seu próprio `.htaccess`

Observação `ExpiresDefault` não tem nada haver com cookies, isto não ativa cookies, ele só define o cache das imagens para o cliente, cookies são dados que gravam no cliente e podem ser reaproveitados e não cache.

Acho que isto deve ajudar:

- [Indicações de uso de cookies?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106906/3635)
- [Guardar ou não cache do navegador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94372/3635)